# Index of empty positions in list

Tags: r, list

I have a list like the following:

```
l <- list(c(1,2,3), integer(), c(4,5), integer(), 7)
```

and in return I want a vector like the following:

```
c(2, 4)
```

which are the positions where list `l` has no elements. I can manage that with:

```
which(unlist(lapply(c(1:(length(l))), function(x) { length(l[[x]]) })) == 0)
```

or even with:

```
as.vector(which(unlist(lapply(l, length)) == 0))
```

but I have the feeling I'm complicating a bit. Is there a simpler way, without using so many functions, to get the index of the empty positions in this list?

Comment: `which(lengths(l)==0)`.

Comment: Awesome. Please answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `lengths` function which gives the length of all the elements of a list:

```
which(lengths(l)==0)
#[1] 2 4
```

The `lengths` function is somewhat "new" (available since R 3.2.0 if I recall correctly). If you have an older R version, this also works (but it's slower):

```
which(sapply(l,length)==0)
```